# How to keep graphics inline with enumerate?

Tags: graphics, enumerate

Having trouble here with creating a list, answering a problem set. For example, the answer to item B) is a graph that I created on Stata. I would like it to start inline with the "B)".

I'm using this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
 % Skipping the whole body until the main problem...%

\section*{Questão2}
\begin{enumerate}[A)]
\item Para que possamos usar \textit{componentes} como instrumento de 
  \textit{educacao}, eles devem ser correlacionados e
  \textit{componentes} não deve afetar o salário/hora

\item \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{componentes}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The image can be shifted via `\raisebox`. In the following example, the image is lowered until the top of the image is at the same height as the top of "B)". Option `demo` is only added because of the missing image file.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\section*{Questão2}
\begin{enumerate}[A)]
\item Para que possamos usar \textit{componentes} como instrumento de
  \textit{educacao}, eles devem ser correlacionados e
  \textit{componentes} não deve afetar o salário/hora

\item
  \raisebox{\heightof{B)}-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{componentes}}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Test]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the `adjustbox` package. This provides a simpler and more memorable interface to the adjustment.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\section*{Questão2}
\begin{enumerate}[A)]
\item Para que possamos usar \textit{componentes} como instrumento de
  \textit{educacao}, eles devem ser correlacionados e
  \textit{componentes} não deve afetar o salário/hora

\item
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{componentes}}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Or `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and then `\includegraphics[...,valign=t]{..}`.